# Regex not giving result as per browser search for chinese characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am facing one issue in regex,

Please refer following link (In Chrome Browser).

https://regex101.com/r/Cb3V25/1

In output there is only one match. But if I do browser search (Ctrl + F) with this に Japanese character then it also shows this ニ Japanese character as highlighted.

I need both of them highlighted. What is the way to do that? There are also other characters which has similar problems, so need answer in general for all thses kind of characters.

Comment: Maybe just use a character class? See https://regex101.com/r/ELSze6/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I need them in general. This is not case for this particular single character only.

Comment: the translation for _[に]_ is _into_ and for _ニ_ is _two_ how you're supposed to match it

Comment: These chars [denote NI letters](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%E3%81%AB%E3%83%8B), but they belong to two different scripts. You must use a custom character class like `[にニ]` to match them.

Answer (score 1):

ニ is the katakana version of に (these are both pronounced "ni"). Chrome apparently implements kana-folding with Ctrl-F. In other words, it finds both katakana and hiragana versions of whatever kana character is being searched for. I don't know how to turn that on or off; I don't think it can be.

Chrome will also do zenkaku/hankaku folding. That is, searching for 1 (hankaku) will find １ (zenkaku, so-called "full-width"), and vice versa. This is similar to case-insensitivity when searching for Roman letters.

This behavior is defined by the [Unicode Collation Algorithm (UCA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_collation_algorithm). I have not been able to determine if browsers are supposed to implement it, in which case lack of this behavior in Firefox would be a bug, or if it's left up to the browser; I suspect the latter. Here is a an old Mozilla bug report requesting this feature: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=71893.

If for some reason you really want to distinguish between hiragana and katakana when doing in-page searching in Chrome, you can install an extension which provides regexp search on the page.

If your objective is to do kana folding with regexp searches, that is not possible. To regexp, these are two different characters, as another answer mentions. There is no "ignore hiragana/katakana distinction" flag in any regexp flavor I'm aware of, nor is there a "ignore zenkaku/hankaku distinction" flag. However, you could write your own little routine to construct such regexps relatively easily.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this is what you wanted:

https://regex101.com/r/Cb3V25/2

Comment: I need them in general. This is not case for this particular single character only.

Comment: にandニare different characters... i don't know why Ctrl + F search has mixed them up